# How to do a Post request in Jquery and passing the Django CSRF token?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-views

I'm trying to realize a POST request in Jquery  to the Django server. The problem is that I need to pass the CSRF token. So I copy [this code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax) in my JS file before the code of the request. But, nothing happens. The Firebug console show me the error 500 (Internal Server Error), and if I change the Post request to a get request, it do the request.

JS File

The copied code

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, settings) {
  function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
function sameOrigin(url) {
    // url could be relative or scheme relative or absolute
    var host = document.location.host; // host + port
    var protocol = document.location.protocol;
    var sr_origin = '//' + host;
    var origin = protocol + sr_origin;
    // Allow absolute or scheme relative URLs to same origin
    return (url == origin || url.slice(0, origin.length + 1) == origin + '/') ||
        (url == sr_origin || url.slice(0, sr_origin.length + 1) == sr_origin + '/') ||
        // or any other URL that isn't scheme relative or absolute i.e relative.
        !(/^(\/\/|http:|https:).*/.test(url));
}
function safeMethod(method) {
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}

if (!safeMethod(settings.type) && sameOrigin(settings.url)) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
}
```

});

My code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $.post('/favorites/delete_favorite/' + data_info[0] + '/' + data_info[1], function(data){
           alert(data);
      });
```

View.py

```
def delete_favorite(request, content_type=None, object_id=None):

    if request.method == 'POST':
         message = "Hello POST"
    else:        
         message = "Hello"

    return HttpResponse(message)
 });
```

**Solution**
I had a error when I sent the url, it missed a slash, so the right solution is:

$(document).ready(function(){
      $.post('/favorites/delete_favorite/' + data_info[0] + '/' + data_info[1] + '/', function(data){
           alert(data);
      });

I don't remove this post, because it's posible someone need it.

Comment: If you're getting a 500 response then the problem is not a CSRF error, that would give you a 403

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for, your views.py file looks fine.

```
$.ajax({
    url:"/favorites/delete_favorite/' + data_info[0] + '/' + data_info[1]",
    type: "POST",
    data: {values:['1','2'], csrfmiddlewaretoken:$("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()},
    success:function(response){
        alert("success: " + response);
    },
    error:function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError){
        alert("xhr status: " + xhr.statusText);
    },

});
```

Alternatively you can use `@csrf_exempt` on the view function:

```
@csrf_exempt
def delete_favorite(request, content_type=None, object_id=None):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        message = "Hello POST"
    else:        
        message = "Hello"

    return HttpResponse(message)
});
```

Comment: This decorator exempts from the protection of CSRF token so I can't do this. The first answer, I don't have the input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken] tag in my template so I can't do this solution now. Is there another solution? Is this solution secure?

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with `django 1.3`, you can use a `javascript` function like this

```
($)(function(){

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        function getCookie(name) {
            var cookieValue = null;
            if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
                var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                    var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                    // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                    if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return cookieValue;
        }
        if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/.test(settings.url))) {
            // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
        }
    }
});

});
```

in this case you can pass your `csrftoken` like so
    {csrftoken: {{csrf_token}}}
along with your `post data`

note this will work well if you use

```
def function(request):
    .....
    ctx = RequestContext(request, {})
    return render_to_response(template, ctx)
```

if you are using `django 1.4`, you need to replace `csrftoken` with `csrfmiddlewaretoken`